# Access Lightsail Instance's database with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, amazon-lightsail

I have an Amazon Lightsail Ubuntu multi WordPress site set up with bitnami stack.

[image]

I'm looking for a way to access the Instance's database on Amazon Lightsail with MySQL Workbench remotely.

Please note that I do not have a seperate Lightsail database, as I'm trying to do things as cheaply as possible at the moment. So the following guide is not applicable to me.

[Connecting to your MySQL database in Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-connecting-to-your-mysql-database)

According the `wp-config.php` MySQL database is using `localhost:3306`

I have static IP address `3.230.xxx.xxx`. I have taken the DB username and password from the `wp_config.php` file.

I've entered the details.

[image]

I wonder if anybody else has managed to connect to an Instance's database, rather than a seperate database.

[image]

If this is not possible I wonder if there are any suggestions as how to best access this Instance's database remotely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer using a similar youtube video which is used to connect to phpMyAdmin.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VdcQLDmYII

Basically you need to use Putty SSH tunneling in order to connect to the MySQL instance

- First I added a new connection in Putty, make sure port 22 is open on
  the LightSail firewall

[image]

- Go to the Connection -> SSH -> Auth tab on the right hand side menu
  Enter your SSH key which is downloaded from the Lightsail dashboard,
  it will need to be converted in the standard recognised by putty

[image]

- Go to Connections -> Data tab on the right hand side menu. Add a new
  forwarded port we are forwarding localhost:3306 on the server to a
  port on our machine 2222

[image]

- Start the connection via Putty.
- Now in MySQL WorkBench go to the connection to database windows.
  Enter the port 2222 I entered the DB user and Password from
  wp-config.php file and was able to successfully connect.

[image]

#### Also found a second method

Within the MySQL Workbench you can change the connection method to `Standard TCP/IP over SSH'. Gave the SSH key and the relevant details on connection was accepted

[image]

Comment: Here is an alternative that worked for me: https://serverfault.com/questions/1014142/remote-connect-to-mysql-aws-lightsail/1014225#1014225

Comment: Second method is what I was looking for and it worked like a charm. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to remotely connect MySQL on Lightsail.
https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-connecting-to-your-mysql-database
**There are 3 steps**:

1. get the endpoint link
2. enable public mode
3. configure MySQL workbench

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answers the question when you use a full 'MySQL managed database' instance.  I don't think it holds for a standard linux instance.  When I orginially raised this question it was for a Bitami stack with MySQL install.   I think you still have to SSH tunnel if you don't have a 'MySQL managed database' instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think this method is applicable when we have separate database instance running. Here in original question it is asked for when database is running locally on wordpress instance.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is it's a instance database, does not have external database IP you can directly connect to,so you need to ssh into the instance first, and then connect to the local db.

Many database management tools have the option to let you connect to database through ssh, in my case I'm using the free version of DBVisualizer.
[image]

add a ssh configuration, fill in your host ip address, username, and ssh key, which can be found in your lightsail home page
[image]

finally, find your db credentials in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php and fill into the form
[image]

you should be able to connect at this point.

reference : https://mead.io/2022/06/30/connect-to-a-wordpress-lightsail-database-from-a-gui/

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have - after a marathon tech support session with AWS :)

Although the Lightsail firewall may say port 3306 is open, the server instance itself may have its own firewall settings which close it. On my case teh AMI that was used to set up the instance was configured that way

I my case it was Ubuntu but here is the summary of the advice I got from AWS--

1. We have connected to the instance via SSH using the user-name 'xxxxxx' from terminal.
   --
   ssh -l xxxxx  34.xxx.xxx.221

---

2. Checked and confirmed that mysql is running on the instance.

---

### systemctl status mysql

3. Confirmed the port on which mysql is running.

---

### netstat -plnae | grep 'pid'

4. Checked the 'ufw' firewall rules and noticed that 3306 is not allowed.

---

### ufw status

5. Opened the port 3306 on ufw firewall

---

### ufw allow 3306

After performing these steps you were able to establish connection to your database

hth